# Font Awesome icons disappearing

Tags: css

My Font Awesome icon is not showing up in my menu. I reference it

```
<i class="fa fa-pencil fa-fw"></i>
```

and call the referring Stylesheet with

```
<link rel='stylesheet' id='taptap-fontawesome-css' href='http://www.omigretchen.de/wp-content/plugins/taptap-by-bonfire/fonts/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css' type='text/css' media='all' />
```

in the header.

It seems like the CSS gets applied correctly (width, et cetera) but the Icon itself is missing. I don't know what else to try so if anyone of you has an idea it is highly appreciated.

Cheers

Michael

Comment: On which pages do you use the icons?

Comment: Hi Remzi! I use it only on www.omigretchen.de. It is one Icon in one of the main menu links. I studied the code a lot of times, but can't figure it out! Seems like only the icons are not loaded! The plug uses 4.7.0 so the code should be correct due to  documentation.

Comment: It´s in front of the menu link "Cotizar y reservar".

Comment: Okay, I will take a look.

Comment: Txh so much! I owe you big one. If you stumble across anything please let me know!

Comment: I can see some icons, see my screenshot: https://imgur.com/oJvTpnb

Comment: You mean the chevron down icons? Or did you mean something else?

Comment: These arrows are not Font Awesome icons, actually, the Font Awesome icons should appear left of the link "Cotizar...". There's a free space now but for some reason the icon itself does not load!

Comment: Actually, when in Console I can see the Font Awesome styles, I can play with them and they seem to trigger, only the Icon is missing. I ruled out Cache problems, as well as browser incompatibility.

Comment: I can see that it being overwitten by an other plugin

Comment: I can only see one reference to Fant Awesome. Can you tell which other Plugin it is that overwrites it?

Comment: I have posted my answer, see below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like that your pencil icon is being overwritten by your theme, see: http://www.omigretchen.de/wp-content/themes/venedor/css/plugins.css
[image]

Therefore, use the following code below to restore it:

```
.fa-pencil:before {
    content: "\f040";
}
```

Edit: Font Awesome 4.7.0 is highly outdated, as of this post, the latest stable version is Font Awesome 5.5.0

The following code will add Font Awesome 5 to you wp website and this will be placed in the footer.

I recommend you doing this with the **Code Snippets plugin** or putting this in your child theme's **functions.php**

```
function add_footer_styles_font_awesome() {
    wp_enqueue_style('fontawesome5', 'https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.5.0/css/all.css', array(), null );
};
add_action( 'get_footer', 'add_footer_styles_font_awesome' );
```

See documentation: https://fontawesome.com/how-to-use/on-the-web/setup/upgrading-from-version-4

Comment: Renzi, you are right, I just found this at the very end of the console. One last question: where would I enter this css rule? Should I add an !important and put it in the general css file?

Comment: Does your theme provide a way to add custom CSS? If not do your customization in a child theme, therefore, you're able to update your (parent) theme safely. Most respectable/serious theme developers provide a child theme or have a documentation to do so.

Comment: If both is not possible or you don't know, use Code Snippets plugin, see: https://wordpress.org/plugins/code-snippets/

Comment: Remzi, thanks a lot, yes, I have a Custom CSS field but I will move everything up to a child theme within the next days! I just got it to work! Thanks a lot for your efforts, really appreciated! A great cheers to you and a happy weekend!

Comment: You're welcome, I'm glad you were able to fix this issue. I have also edited my answer to included some advice about upgrading Font Awesome.